# difference between $log.log() and console.log() in Angular Js

Tags: angularjs

What is the difference when using $log.log() and console.log().

What is a scenario that typically use $log.log() than console.log()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$log` is a simple service for logging. Default implementation safely writes the message to the browser's console (if present).

This means that unlike `console.log()`, it `$log` is a service that first checks if `console.log()` is supported. For instance in older versions of IE `console.log()` is unsupported and would cause an error that could cause your page not to work because of the javascript error.

Otherwise, you would have to write the following At the top of your script so if console is used in an unsupported browser instead of getting an undefined error it will just return an empty function:

```
if ( ! window.console ) console = { log: function(){} };
```

Reference:
[docs.angularjs.org](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$log)

Comment: And presumably, one could use something other than the default implementation as well, to log in creative ways, without changes in application code.

Comment: Also, it prevents you from using a global, which is also good.